# In regression, if the residuals are correlated with X then what assumption has most likely been violated?

Tags: regression, assumptions

1. independence
2. homoscedasticity

---

This question is from an online quiz with one "correct" answer, but I'm not sure I agree. I understand that the answer is homoscedasticity, but isn't independence violated here as well? Since heteroskedasticity indicates that residuals are correlated with X, then there is a *dependency* with x. Therefore, independence is also violated.

Could someone please explain?

Comment: The OLS _residuals_ are by construction orthogonal to $X$. They also have zero mean, again by construction. So "residuals correlated with X" makes no sense. Perhaps "errors correlated with $X$"?

Comment: If you have the question right, both answers are wrong; even if they're there, the residuals are still uncorrelated with $x$. [Right now I can think of two ways to make that happen: (i) leaving out the intercept;  (ii) leaving out that $x$ that you're checking correlation with.]

Answer (score 1):

As both @AlecosPapadopoulos and @Glen_b note, there is a problem with the question.  Since they said the answer was 2 (heteroscedasticity), I wonder if they meant to ask: 'In regression, if the [*standard deviation* of the] residuals are correlated with X then what assumption has most likely been violated?'  However, that would be an awkward way to get at that idea (certainly not the question I would ask to probe that issue) and "are" should be "is" to maintain proper number agreement.

An alternative interpretation would be 'In regression, if the residuals are correlated with <strike>X then</strike> [*themselves*,] what assumption has most likely been violated?'  This would make your choice of 1 (independence) correct.  A variable correlated with itself (at some lag) is *autocorrelated*, which @Stat discusses.  This can happen when the functional form of the variable is misspecified.  For example, if the relationship between $X$ and $Y$ is curvilinear, but a straight line is fit, then you may have, say, several negative residuals in a row, followed by several positive residuals in a row, followed by several negative residuals in a row again.

In sum, the question is flawed.  Without more information from the asker, it is impossible to say exactly what the deal is.

Comment: It would make sense if it said "... if the squared residuals ..."  That is an easy mistake to make in writing up a test.

Comment: @Bill, good point; that seems more likely.